# Error: "The method is undefined for type", and "The constructor is undefined"

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I was writing my program when I came across the following errors at certain spots in my code:

The first error was: "The constructor Gerbil(String, String, int[], boolean, boolean, String[]) is undefined" at the following code: gerbil[i] = new Gerbil(n5,n6,amountfood, escape[i], bite[i],food);

The second error was: "The method getTypeFood() is undefined for the type Gerbil" at the following code: String[]food = g.getTypeFood();

Here is my entire code for the program (2 different classes)

1st class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Gerbilfood {
    static int n8;
    static int n3;
    static String n55;
    static String n35;
    static String n2;
    public static Gerbil[] gerbil;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input how many types of food items the  gerbils           eat as an integer");
        String n0 = scanner.nextLine();
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(n0);

        String[] food = new String[n1];

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a food name");

            String n2 = scanner.nextLine();

            food[i] = n2;

            int[] maximum = new int[n1];

            System.out.println("Please enter maximum amount of this food per day");
            String n33 = scanner.nextLine();
            int n3 = Integer.parseInt(n33);
            maximum[i] = n3;
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter in the number of gerbils in the lab");
        String n73 = scanner.nextLine();
        int n4 = Integer.parseInt(n73);
        //gerbil = new Gerbil[n4];

         gerbil = new Gerbil[n4];

        int[] combo = new int[n4];
        String[] ids = new String[n4];
        for (int i = 0; i < n4; i++) {

            //Gerbil g = new Gerbil(n1);

            System.out.println("Please enter in the lab id for one of the gerbils");
            String n5 = scanner.nextLine();
            //g.setId(n5);

            //ids[i] = n5;

            //String[] names = new String[n4];

            System.out.println("Please enter in the name given to gerbil whose lab id you just entered");
            String n6 = scanner.nextLine(); // gerbil name
            //g.setName(n6);

            //String[] amountfood = new String[n1];
            int [] amountfood = new int[n1];

            for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
                System.out.println("how much of " +food[j]

                        + " did this gerbil eat");
                String n8 = scanner.nextLine();
                //amountfood[j = n8;
                amountfood[j] = Integer.parseInt(n8);

            }
            boolean[] bite = new boolean[n4];
                System.out
                        .println("Does this Gerbil bite? Enter True or False");
                String n77 = scanner.nextLine();
                if (n77.equalsIgnoreCase("True"))

                bite[i] = true;
                else{
                    bite[i] = false;
                }

                boolean[]escape = new boolean[n4];
                System.out
                          .println("Does this Gerbil escape? Enter True or False");
            String n89 = scanner.nextLine();

            if (n89.equalsIgnoreCase("True"))

            escape[i] = true;

            else{ 
                escape[i] = false;
            }


            gerbil[i] = new Gerbil(n5,n6,amountfood, escape[i], bite[i],food);

            }



            System.out.println("What information would you like to know?");
            String n55 = scanner.nextLine();

            String n33 = "search";
            String n34 = "average";
            String n35 = "restart";
            String n36 = "quit";

            if(n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n34)){
            System.out.println( averagefood());

        }
            else{
                if(n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n33)){

                    System.out.println("Please type the lab id of the gerbil you wish to search for");

                    String n87 = scanner.nextLine();

                      Gerbil g = searchForGerbil(n87);

                    Gerbil  gerbilattributes=searchForGerbil(n87);

                    String gerbid = g.getId();

                    String gerbname = g.getName();

                    boolean gerbbite = g.getBite();

                    boolean gerbescape = g.getEscape();



                    for (int i = 0; i<n1; i++)

                    String[]food = g.getTypeFood();

                    int[]   gerbfoods = g.getAmountFood();

                    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)



                    System.out.println(gerbid +" bite = "+ gerbbite + "             " + gerbname + "escape = " + gerbescape + " " + gerbfoods);



                }
                else{
                    if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n35)){

                    //GO BACK
                    }
                    else{
                        if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n36)){

                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}








    public static String averagefood() {

        int i = 0;
        Gerbil g = gerbil[i];
       String gid = g.getId();

        String gname = g.getName();
        long percent = Math.round(n8 * 100.0 / n3);

        String everything = gid + " " + gname + " " + percent + "\n";
        for ( i = 0; i <=gerbil.length; i++) {







            //turn everything;
             } 


        return everything;
    }

    public static Gerbil searchForGerbil(String n87) {


            for(int i = 0; i< gerbil.length; i++){
                Gerbil g = gerbil[i];

                if(n87.equals(g.getId())){
                return gerbil[i]; 



            }


        // return (new Gerbil[i]);

    } return null;

}
}

second class:

public class Gerbil {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int[] amountfood;
    private int numbergerbils;
    private String[] food;

    private boolean escape;
    private boolean bite;

    public Gerbil(String n5, String n6, int[]numOfFood, boolean newEscape, boolean newBite, String[] n2) {

        id = n5;
        name = n6;
        amountfood = numOfFood;
        escape = newEscape;
        bite = newBite;
        food = n2;
    }

    public Gerbil(String[] typefood){

        food = typefood;
    }
    public Gerbil(int [] numOfFood) {
        amountfood = numOfFood;


    }


public int[]  getAmountFood(){


    return  amountfood;
}

public boolean getBite(){

return bite;
}

public boolean getEscape(){

return escape;
}
    public String getId() {




        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(String newId) {
        id = newId;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

public String [] getTypeFood(){

        return food;

        return null;
    }

}
```

Please input how many types of food items the  gerbils  eat as an integer

2

Please enter a food name

bread

Please enter maximum amount of this food per day

5

Please enter a food name

garlic

Please enter maximum amount of this food per day

6

Please enter in the number of gerbils in the lab

2

Please enter in the lab id for one of the gerbils

hgklll

Please enter in the name given to gerbil whose lab id you just entered

larry

how much of bread did this gerbil eat

1

how much of garlic did this gerbil eat

1

Does this Gerbil bite? Enter True or False

False

Does this Gerbil escape? Enter True or False

True

Please enter in the lab id for one of the gerbils

hjdddd

Please enter in the name given to gerbil whose lab id you just entered

dave

how much of bread did this gerbil eat

1

how much of garlic did this gerbil eat

1

Does this Gerbil bite? Enter True or False

False

Does this Gerbil escape? Enter True or False

True

What information would you like to know?

search

Please type the lab id of the gerbil you wish to search for

hjdddd
hjdddd bite = false             daveescape = true [I@629e5e21
hjdddd bite = false             daveescape = true [I@629e5e21

For the last part (Please type in the lab id you wish to search for), I am trying to get it to return the food names and amounts in the string. Example: Name: Big Bertha (will escape, will not bite), Food: Red Pill – 25/50, Blue Pill – 
50/100

Comment: What do you think the errors mean?

Comment: Also, recompile your code.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file for `Gerbil`?

Comment: Yeah I am sure, and I have no idea what they mean

Comment: Have you tried formatting/indenting the code appropriately in order to see if you have matched your curly-braces correctly?

Comment: Kind of..im pretty sure they match up fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance below method is wrong hence Gerbil class will not compile.

```
public String [] getTypeFood(){

    return food;

    return null;
}
```

Remove one of the return statement.

```
public String [] getTypeFood(){
  return food;

}
```

Full code:

```
public class Gerbil {

private String id;
private String name;
private int[] amountfood;
private int numbergerbils;
private String[] food;

private boolean escape;
private boolean bite;

public Gerbil(String n5, String n6, int[] numOfFood, boolean newEscape, boolean newBite, String[] n2) {

    id = n5;
    name = n6;
    amountfood = numOfFood;
    escape = newEscape;
    bite = newBite;
    food = n2;
}

public Gerbil(String[] typefood) {

    food = typefood;
}

public Gerbil(int[] numOfFood) {
    amountfood = numOfFood;

}

public int[] getAmountFood() {

    return amountfood;
}

public boolean getBite() {

    return bite;
}

public boolean getEscape() {

    return escape;
}

public String getId() {

    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(String newId) {
    id = newId;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public String[] getTypeFood() {

    return food;


}

}



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gerbilfood {

static int n8;
static int n3;
static String n55;
static String n35;
static String n2;
public static Gerbil[] gerbil;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input how many types of food items the  gerbils           eat as an integer");
    String n0 = scanner.nextLine();
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(n0);

    String[] food = new String[n1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a food name");

        String n2 = scanner.nextLine();

        food[i] = n2;

        int[] maximum = new int[n1];

        System.out.println("Please enter maximum amount of this food per day");
        String n33 = scanner.nextLine();
        int n3 = Integer.parseInt(n33);
        maximum[i] = n3;
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter in the number of gerbils in the lab");
    String n73 = scanner.nextLine();
    int n4 = Integer.parseInt(n73);
    //gerbil = new Gerbil[n4];

    gerbil = new Gerbil[n4];

    int[] combo = new int[n4];
    String[] ids = new String[n4];
    for (int i = 0; i < n4; i++) {

        //Gerbil g = new Gerbil(n1);
        System.out.println("Please enter in the lab id for one of the gerbils");
        String n5 = scanner.nextLine();
        //g.setId(n5);

        //ids[i] = n5;
        //String[] names = new String[n4];
        System.out.println("Please enter in the name given to gerbil whose lab id you just entered");
        String n6 = scanner.nextLine(); // gerbil name
        //g.setName(n6);

        //String[] amountfood = new String[n1];
        int[] amountfood = new int[n1];

        for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
            System.out.println("how much of " + food[j]
                    + " did this gerbil eat");
            String n8 = scanner.nextLine();
            //amountfood[j = n8;
            amountfood[j] = Integer.parseInt(n8);

        }
        boolean[] bite = new boolean[n4];
        System.out
                .println("Does this Gerbil bite? Enter True or False");
        String n77 = scanner.nextLine();
        if (n77.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
            bite[i] = true;
        } else {
            bite[i] = false;
        }

        boolean[] escape = new boolean[n4];
        System.out
                .println("Does this Gerbil escape? Enter True or False");
        String n89 = scanner.nextLine();

        if (n89.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
            escape[i] = true;
        } else {
            escape[i] = false;
        }

        gerbil[i] = new Gerbil(n5, n6, amountfood, escape[i], bite[i], food);

    }

    System.out.println("What information would you like to know?");
    String n55 = scanner.nextLine();

    String n33 = "search";
    String n34 = "average";
    String n35 = "restart";
    String n36 = "quit";

    if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n34)) {
        System.out.println(averagefood());

    } else {
        if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n33)) {

            System.out.println("Please type the lab id of the gerbil you wish to search for");

            String n87 = scanner.nextLine();

            Gerbil g = searchForGerbil(n87);

            Gerbil gerbilattributes = searchForGerbil(n87);

            String gerbid = g.getId();

            String gerbname = g.getName();

            boolean gerbbite = g.getBite();

            boolean gerbescape = g.getEscape();

            for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
                food = g.getTypeFood();
            }


                int[] gerbfoods = g.getAmountFood();

             System.out.print("Lab :"+gerbid + " Name:"+ gerbname + " ("+ ((gerbbite==true)?"will bite":"will not bite")  +  "," + ((gerbescape==true)?"will escape":"will not escape") + ")");
            for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
                System.out.print( " " + food[i] + ":"+ gerbfoods[i]);
            }

        } else {
            if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n35)) {

                //GO BACK
            } else {
                if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n36)) {

                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static String averagefood() {

    int i = 0;
    Gerbil g = gerbil[i];
    String gid = g.getId();

    String gname = g.getName();
    long percent = Math.round(n8 * 100.0 / n3);

    String everything = gid + " " + gname + " " + percent + "\n";
    for (i = 0; i <= gerbil.length; i++) {

        //turn everything;
    }

    return everything;
}

public static Gerbil searchForGerbil(String n87) {

    for (int i = 0; i < gerbil.length; i++) {
        Gerbil g = gerbil[i];

        if (n87.equals(g.getId())) {
            return gerbil[i];

        }

    // return (new Gerbil[i]);
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

Comment: O ok did u just change the null part, because I already fixed that part and its still giving me the same errors

Comment: No not only that look at the change of   String[]food = g.getTypeFood(); to  food = g.getTypeFood(); 
remove the String[]. this is due to that variable is already define

Comment: This is identical to my answer.

Comment: it worked, but the method I was trying to get working is still giving the wrong output, but the errors are gone at least

Comment: Please share input data and expected output.

Comment: could i like post it someother way here because i am trying to paste what i got from executing it here, but it says on this site that its too long

Comment: ok cool, I tried it and it worked...i have another question about the other average method I had defined as, the output is fine, but when I input like 2 or more gerbils for the amount of gerbils, it only outputs data for the first one entered

Comment: It is because of searchForGerbil returns only one instance

Comment: No, I am talking about this method --> public static String averagefood() . It is supposed to return data for all gerbils, but only returns it for the first one entered

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your two classes in two separate, appropriately named files, here are the two problems:

In Gerbilfood, in your `main` method you are attempting to redefine the variable food:

```
String[] food = new String[n1];
...
String[]food = g.getTypeFood();
```

In Gerbil, your getTypeFood method has two returns:

```
public String [] getTypeFood(){
    return food;
    return null;
}
```

Start by fixing these two problems.

Comment: Ok, so I took out the return null. For the first thing you mentioned though, would i just store "g.getTypeFood" to a different array name such as String [] foodnames = g.getTypeFood(); ?

Comment: That would depend on what you want your code to do. Without spending a lot of time trying to understand what exactly you are trying to do, I would start with `food = g.getTypeFood();`.

Comment: hmmmm i mean im trying to save the method where an array is returned for a specific object of food types and amounts to a variable which i can include in my concatenated string which prints out all of the attributes

Comment: Once you fix the items I identified, the code will compile.